# Handling complex object trees in QML's model-view-delegate system?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, qml

I'm using QML with PyQt, and these two communicate with Qt's signal/slot system. I have Python objects which I've serialized to a JSON format, for example a list of stores and items sold in them:

```
[
  {
    "store": "Walmart",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "price": 0.95
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "store": "Target",
    "items": [...]
  },
  ...
]
```

This is then forwarded to QML with a signal, and then I store the whole JSON structure into a single variable, let's call it `stores`:

```
// main.qml
Window {
    id: app
    property var stores: []

    // Slot function that's connected to Python
    function onStoresInitialized(stores) {
        app.stores = stores;
    }
}
```

Now I have a `ListView` like so:

```
ListView {
    model: app.stores
    delegate: Column {
        Repeater {
            model: modelData["items"]
            Text {
                text: modelData["name"] + " $" + modelData["price"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While the example is greatly simplified, it all seems to work fine up to this point. The problem arises when I want to update a single item, say we get a signal from Python that a particular item's price was updated. Our QML slot would look something like this:

```
function updatePrice(storeName, itemName, newPrice) {
    for (let store : app.stores) {
        if (store["name"] === storeName) {
            for (let item : store["items"]) {
                if (item["name"] === itemName) {
                    item["price"] = newPrice;
                    return;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This properly updates the price in my "model", but it doesn't signal the view of this change. I believe using raw data as a model is not the correct approach, but what is? All the QML guides seem to use simple data examples such as a 1D list of items with `ListModel` and `ListElement`s, but what to do when I have a deep object tree such as here?

Answer (score 1):

My QML days are long over, but one way to deal with this is to wrap the whole JSON into a custom object graph made with PyQt exposing the individual properties as `pyqtProperty`. And then massage the JSON into this object tree. We do this with a C++-model generated from a model specification in Python. It's a long story why it is that way, but it allows us to send JSON over the wire.

There might be a way to do all this in QML itself using QML types, but my personal preference for model creation would be in Python.